# What is wrong in my script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is wrong in my small script when I press the jquery button. It does not open the url. I'm missing a comma some where.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#include-from-outside').load('https://www.*******.com');
</script>

<a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="addTab('jquery','<div id='include-from-outside'></div>')">jquery</a>
```

Comment: Which 'addTab' are you trying to call? Is it this one: http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/layout/tabs2.php ?

Comment: Check the request state in the console. If that is a request to a third party domain you could be being blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: I try not to use iframe.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the `'` for the id to `\"`:-

```
<a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="addTab('jquery','<div id=\"include-from-outside\"></div>')">jquery</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few potential issues with this.. the onclick="addTab(...);

In your script you want to create a function that it is calling. I pulled up the jqueryeasyui page, and looked into the function you were calling.. Try adding this to your page.

```
<script>
function addTab(title, url){
    if ($('#tt').tabs('exists', title)){
        $('#tt').tabs('select', title);
    } else {
        var content = '<iframe scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"  src="'+url+'" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>';
        $('#tt').tabs('add',{
            title:title,
            content:content,
            closable:true
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

In general.. an onclick="addTab()" <-- will call the addTab function in your script. So when you create the function above, this will handle the variables you are passing into it.

Comment: I try not to use iframe

Comment: Clinton, just so I understand what you are trying to do. You want to open a webpage outside of your domain correct all over client-side correct? Other then using an iFrame, there isn't really an easy solution for that. 

If you created a server side script to open the page, and passed it back to client you could get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing a static `html` as a parameter, you don't need it as a parameter to `javascript` function. Also, you can embed the click event in your `href`.

```
<a href="javascript:addTab('jquery');" class="easyui-linkbutton">jquery</a>
<script>
function addTab(language)
{  
    var html = "<div id='include-from-outside'></div>";
    alert(language);
}
</script>
```